# Make an really simple ajax example work

Tags: ajax

I am learning ajax but I have a problem even just trying the example given in w3 tutorial.

When I click the Button there is no change on my page. I don't know what is missing to make it work. Do I need put on my mamp server?

Thank you for your help

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("POST","ajax_info.html",false);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDiv"><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To run the above code there is no need to start your server. 
First check if you have created **ajax_info.html** file or not.
Place **ajax_info.html** in the same folder where the present code file is placed.

Comment: Thank you. I actually already done that. I ll try again cos I must have missed something

Comment: Nope it not the problem. Do i need to write someting specific in ajax-info.html?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try a "GET" instead of a "POST" `xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.html",false);`. Also W3School's example is **NOT IDEAL** and scales **VERY POORLY** once you add more AJAX calls. I recommend switching to a simpler library such as jQuery or AngularJS (bit more advanced) ASAP in order to handle your AJAX calls